# Convert String into ArrayList<MyClass>

Tags: java, collections

I want to convert a `String` **myString** like that:

```
[ ["cd",5,6,7], ["rtt",55,33,12], ["by65",87,87,12] ]
```

into an `ArrayList<CustomClass>`

Where `CustomClass` have constructor :

```
public CustomClass (String name, int num1, int num2, int num3)
```

I tried first to create `ArrayList` of `Strings` :

```
List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myString.split("[")));
```

Didn't worked for me...

How can I get something like that:

```
List - {CustomClass,CustomClass,CustomClass,CustomClass}
```

first `CustomClass = CustomClass.name="cd" , CustomClass.num1=5,CustomClass.num2=7...`

second `CustomClass = CustomClass.name="rtt",CustomClass.num1=55,CustomClass.num2=55...`

and so on...

Comment: "Didn't worked for me..." How did it not work?  What did you expect to get from your split command that is different than what you actually got?  Why are you splitting on "[" in the first place, when your object data is separated by commas?

Comment: Also, custom parsing is not the easiest thing in the world.  Is there any way you can get your input string to be given to you in a common format such as JSON?  Then you could just use an off-the-shelf parser such as Gson to build your object.

Comment: I added the result that I would like to get - a List ob objects

Comment: `String#split()` returns an array of `String`.  There is no way to get a `List<CustomClass>` from that function.  You will need to write some sort of parser/builder.

Comment: Did you consider writing your own simple parser (check if you are inside nested `[...]`, read each field separated by `,` until you find closing `]`). You regular expressions could save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like. If you cant guarantee the string formats then you may have to add additional checks for spliced array length and indexing.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class CustomClass {
    String name;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    public CustomClass(String name, int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "[ [\"cd\",5,6,7], [\"rtt\",55,33,12], [\"by65\",87,87,12] ]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str.substring(1));
        List<CustomClass> customList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
        while (m.find()) {
            String[] arguments = m.group(1).split(",");
            customList.add(new CustomClass(arguments[0], 
                                            Integer.parseInt(arguments[1]), 
                                            Integer.parseInt(arguments[2]), 
                                            Integer.parseInt(arguments[3])));
        }
    }

}
```

**Gson solution**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "[ [\"cd\",5,6,7], [\"rtt\",55,33,12], [\"by65\",87,87,12] ]";
    List<CustomClass> customList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
    String[][] data = new Gson().fromJson(json, String[][].class);
    for (String[] strArray : data){
        customList.add(new CustomClass(strArray[0], 
                Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]), 
                Integer.parseInt(strArray[2]), 
                Integer.parseInt(strArray[3])));
    }
    System.out.println(customList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Syam S ,Is this solution is better that using  JSONArray ?

Comment: If its a json string string then its better to use json array. Then you could create it in 2 or 3 lines using standard json parser like gson or jackson.

Comment: Its a SOAP response, but the response is only one parameter and that is a String that I showed [[data],[data]... ] so I don't know what would be the best for it... is it really 2-3 lines in gson? can you show please how it implemetes

Comment: It depends on how your json data is. gson can read a json string directly to a list of custom objects, but for that we need to have field names and all. In your case it wont be as simple as 2-3 lines. If its just a response string from a SOAP response probably you could follow the above program.

Comment: Updated my answer. That is one way of handling your string as a json. Alternatively you can write a custom deserializer which can be a bit over-kill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick "by-hand" parser for you.

```
public static List<CustomClass> parseString(String str) {
    String [] elements = str.split("\\[");
    List <CustomClass> result = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();

    for (String elem : elements) {
        if (elem.contains("]")) {
            String seq = elem.substring(0, elem.indexOf(']'));
            String [] tokens = seq.split(",");
            result.add(new CustomClass(tokens[0].substring(1,tokens[0].length()-1),
                    Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]),
                    Integer.parseInt(tokens[3])));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Beware that I relied on guaranteed correct input. You might want to tweak this one for what you need.