# How to convert List<String> to List<MyClass>?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How would you convert `List<String>` to `List<MyClass>`? Here's my code:

```
String[] input1Array = input1.split(",");

List<String> stringList1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input1Array));           
List<MyClass> input1List = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

I am trying to parse lines from a csv file and store it in List. 
I need other ways than the obvious one of iterating each element of the String List and adding it to the List of MyClass

Comment: Can you please post your MyClass code as well, also want to understand why you want to do that

Comment: You'd iterate over the strings, and for each one parse it somehow to create a MyClass instance, and add that instance to the List<MyClass>. If that answer is too broad, it's because your question is very broad. What parts of that process are you specifically having trouble with? If it's the parsing, what _about_ the parsing? The more specific you can make your question, the better.

Comment: *I need other ways than the obvious one of iterating each element of the String List and adding it to the List of MyClass.* Says who? Why?

Comment: The only way other than parsing-and-adding is to do a lazy transform, as with Guava's [List.transform](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)). Otherwise, there's no getting around the fact that you'll be iterating over the strings (one way or another) and adding MyClasses (one way or another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make you own split function that returns your class.

2) Or one that returns a class called YourString.  Then extend YourClass with YourString, then your string class will fit in the same array.

EDIT:

```
MyString[] input1Array = mySplit(input1);

List<MyString> stringList1 = new ArrayList<MyString>(Arrays.asList(input1Array));           
List<MyClass> input1List = new ArrayList<MyClass>(stringList1); 

class MyString{
    private String myString;
    public MyString(String input)
    {
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyString{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}

public MyString[] mySplit(String inputString)
{
      ArrayList<MyString> eachMyString = new ArrayList<MyString>();
      //loop through each char in inputString and add each to eachMyString   ArrayList
      return eachMyString.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Can you please give me example of the second one?

Comment: @CM1 The first one is the easiest option.  You have to split the String in Objects, one way or another.  Just split the string into the final product.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998055/convert-string-into-arraylistmyclass - I see that the first answer to this question is helpful to me